# SQL select true if date comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Is it possible to return a boolean value as a select field if a date is less than a certain time?

For example, something like:

```
SELECT true IF (mydate < NOW())
```

or something like that?

Comment: `mydate < NOW()` alone is sufficient..it returns 1 or 0 for true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CAST(CASE WHEN mydate< getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS mydate
FROM
    MyTable WHERE (ID = 1)


-- Another approach might be 

SELECT
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS bit) AS mydate
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    ID = 1 AND mydate < getdate()
```

Comment: IF you dont want the where clause you can just remove it .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inject an inline IF statement as below:

```
SELECT CAST(IIF(mydate < GETDATE(), 1, 0) AS BIT)
```